# What can i do to resize the text and not show the ... in UIPickerView?

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I am using 3 PickerViews and a few words are big and dont fit in PickerView and appear like this "IamAWordVer..." and i dont want this to happen. I want it resize the font or something like to fit all word in the PickerView but i dont to affect the size of the PickerView or the font size of the others picker views including the words in this PickerView where it happens.

For example all words use a default and if dont fit resize to fit all word.

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    let pickerLabel = UILabel()

    if pickerView == pvOne{
        pickerLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        pickerLabel.attributedText = oneText[row] as? NSAttributedString
    }
    else if(pickerView == pvTwo){
        pickerLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        pickerLabel.attributedText = twoText[row] as? NSAttributedString
    }
    else if(pickerView == pvThree){
        pickerLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        pickerLabel.attributedText = threeText[row] as? NSAttributedString
    }
    return pickerLabel
}
```

It show all empty now

Comment: Update your question with your `pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:` method.

Comment: Updated, i think this what you asked.

Comment: Where's the rest of the code? What you posted simply returns an empty label.

Comment: That is my problem i dont know what put more :(

Comment: Were you using this method before posting your question?

Comment: I am using in the ViewController. I gonna update the code for what i am trying it show all empty now

Comment: where do you declare pvOne, pvTwo etc

Comment: Its global and it work because i use in other things

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `nameOfLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true` on it.

Comment: Yes, assuming they are using the `pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:` delegate method and  passing in a label.

Comment: I am trying doing it in this `func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView?) -> UIView` but i dont know where i use the of the label i was trying this to inside `let pickerLabel = UILabel()` but this is a new

Answer (score 1):

I solved this way:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    let pickerLabel = UILabel()


    if pickerView == pvOne{
        pickerLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        let titleData = oneText[row]
        let myTitle = NSAttributedString(string: titleData as! String, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 20.0)!,NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.blackColor()])
        pickerLabel.attributedText = myTitle

    }
    else if(pickerView == pvTwo){
        pickerLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        let titleData = twoText[row]
        let myTitle = NSAttributedString(string: titleData as! String, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 20.0)!,NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.blackColor()])
        pickerLabel.attributedText = myTitle
    }
    else if(pickerView == pvThree){
        pickerLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        let titleData = threeText[row]
        let myTitle = NSAttributedString(string: titleData as! String, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 20.0)!,NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.blackColor()])
        pickerLabel.attributedText = myTitle
    }
    return pickerLabel
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are casting a String to NSAttributedString.

Try:

```
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusingView view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    let pickerLabel = UILabel()

    if pickerView == pvOne{
        pickerLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        pickerLabel.text = oneText[row]
    }
    else if(pickerView == pvTwo){
        pickerLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        pickerLabel.text = twoText[row]
    }
    else if(pickerView == pvThree){
        pickerLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        pickerLabel.text = threeText[row]
    }
    return pickerLabel
}
```